# WidgetKit and WebSocket in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, websocket

Will the widget work, listen and update if I want to use Websocket (Apollo subscription) for widget?

Or widget will not stay alive all the time and the connection from the websocket will drop?

Anybody with some experience

Comment: Widget entries are like screenshots and the widget itself is like a gif. They don’t listen or react you have to reload the timeline if you want to change it.

Comment: Thank's, they will react/update from notification for example but will they keep open websocket session

Comment: @zdravkozdravkin They can't keep Websocket connection alive because iOS won't allow it. It is just a snapshot, not a process like an iOS app when running.

Comment: So I guess is the same for listening for a network via NWPathMonitor(). Can not listen all the time if the device is connected to the internet or not.